# How can I combine the letters in c?

Tags: c

I have been learning c in university and I have a question for you the question is that
I have four letters like that
aaaa and I want to combine them with all alphabet like
aaaa
abaa
acaa
.
.
.
zzzy
zzzz

Thanks from now
Edit: I have  made it more clear in the comments

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your attempt and we can discuss about it...

Comment: What mean "combine them with all alphabet"? You want to generate all possible strings with length == 4? Did you try to code your task?

Comment: Make it by hand, and you will find the algorithm...

Comment: for(j='a'; j<='z';j++)
{
for(k='a'; k<='z';k++){
printf("%c%c",j, k);
printf("\n");

}
Print("\t");
}

Output:
aa  ba .  .  .  za
ab  bb .  .  .  zb
.      .
.      .
az   bz .  .  .  zz I have written that for 2 letters but there should be 4 letters and by using for loop it is really time consuming and I want to do it by using for loop as a function  can I call function in function

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by combine with all letters?

Comment: I mean combine all letters each others aaaa abaa acaa.... azaa/ aaba aaca aada like that

Comment: So you've done it for two? Why can't you apply the same logic to four? Yes it's not efficient but it's not an efficient problem to solve computationally. Analytically we know the answer is 26*26*26*26 combinations if repetition is allowed which equates to 456976 possible combinations of letters - or 45976 iterations in total which isn't exactly going to be quick.

Comment: For now maybe it isn't  so much time consuming but after I did those codes I will add numbers . Now the question is that can I use call functions in functions I will be more easy to do this program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the introductory [tour] some time. You may want use **[edit]** to add all necessary information to your question, instead of having it scattered it over several comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done it for two, the same logic can be applied (albeit inefficiently) to four:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char one, two, three, four;
    char output[5] = "aaaa";

    for (one = 'a'; one <= 'z'; one++)
    {
        output[0] = one;
        for (two = 'a'; two <= 'z'; two++)
        {
            output[1] = two;
            for (three = 'a'; three <= 'z'; three++)
            {
                output[2] = three;
                for (four = 'a'; four <= 'z'; four++)
                {
                    output[3] = four;
                    printf("%s\n", output);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and I liked your code also as I see you used arrays in this code it is easier than my code

Comment: Can I add also numbers in this code? I mean I want to use numbers and letters can I? like a1bc a0dw can I get these outputs?

Comment: Numbers can also be represented by `char` in c. If you make either of the characters in the loop start at `'0'` instead of `'a'` you can iterate through the numbers in the same way as you can letters. I'll let you figure out how to arrange it yourself though as it will be a good learning exercise!